# VS15 библиотеки компоновщика

Tags: c++, visual-studio, библиотеки, компоновщик

Каждый раз когда делаю **новый** проект приходится прописывать библиотеки для opengl

```
glaux.lib
glu32.lib
glui32.lib
glut32.lib
opengl32.lib
```

Как сделать чтобы эти библиотеки были по умолчанию в компоновщике Visual Studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для Windows, `#pragma comment( lib, "glaux")` и т.д., в любом `*.cpp` или `*.h` файле, добавит эти зависимости, если Вас устроит `copy-paste`-вариант. Обычно к проектам подключается какой-то минимальный набор своих файлов ("болванка"). Вполне логично было бы разместить эти зависимости там.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого существуют [Property Sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e(v=vs.90).aspx). Я записал [gif-ку](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NNWc6drLUJE/VePi5NLTizI/AAAAAAAAGt4/ixIADi6xKwg/s0/property_sheet.gif).
Сначала откройте окно Property Manager в Visual Studio. (Edit->Other windows->Property manager).

Затем нажмите Add New Project Property Sheet. 
Введите имя (скажем, "Opengl") и сохраните в какой-нибудь удобной для вас директории (общей для всех проектов).
В дереве Property Manager появится новый Property Sheet "Opengl".
Откройте его свойства и добавьте нужные библиотеки в опции линкера.
Сохраните настройки.

Теперь вы можете использовать полученный `Opengl.props` во всех новых проектах.
После создания нового проекта, вам надо будет открыть Property Manager и нажать Add Existing Property Sheet.

Вы также можете редактировать дефолтные Property Sheets (например, Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user) и тогда эти библиотеки будут подключаться ко всем проектам на C++ по умолчанию, но это не рекомендуется.